# Call to undefined function g5plus_get_option() in public_html/wp-content/themes/g5-beyot/header.php on line 18

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

While uploading a fresh theme of G5 Beyot | Shared By VestaThemes.com on WordPress I am facing the issue of

```
Call to undefined function g5plus_get_option() in public_html/mydirectory/wp-content/themes/g5-beyot/header.php on line 19.
```

Website is also showing the site is experiencing technical difficulties as Wordpress error

I searched on google and tried different approaches to solve this issue but could not find a perfect answer.

Below is the code of header.php

```
$header_layout = g5plus_get_option('header_layout', 'header-1');

  $header_responsive = g5plus_get_option('header_responsive_breakpoint', 
  '991px');

  ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Open Html -->

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!-- Open Head -->
<head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<!-- Close Head -->

<body <?php body_class(); ?> `data-responsive="<?php echo` 

esc_attr($header_responsive) ?>"



 `data-header="<?php echo` `esc_attr($header_layout) ?>">`
```

Hope I will get the answer to my question.

Comment: What approaches did you try exactly that did not work ?

Comment: I comment out the $header_layout as well as $header_responsive line and tried to use my custom code to call header-1 but it failed .